# Handshake failed due to invalid Upgrade header in Tomcat deployed in EBS

Tags: java, spring, tomcat, ssl, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have a java spring application deployed in a tomcat 8 environment in Amazon elastic beanstalk server. The application has HTTPS configured with proper certificate. When a socket connection connect the application I am getting below error in log

```
ERROR o.s.w.s.s.s.DefaultHandshakeHandler - Handshake failed due to invalid Upgrade header: null
```

I tried to figure out over internet, some post is saying it need to enable HTTPS. HTTPS is already enabled and normal webservice calls to the same server works.

Please let me know if anyone has any idea. Thank you !

Comment: Is this relevant? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31211919/spring-websocket-handshake-failed-due-to-invalid-upgrade-header-null

Comment: @AnandBhat HTTPS is already enabled in my instance security group.

Comment: @APaul did you find the solution? I am facing the same, could you please share the solution

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is the elastic beanstalk uses a proxy, so you can configure the proxy to support sockets.

The default proxy to Tomcat is Apache, I have changed it to nginx with the next file:

**.ebextensions\nginx-proxy.config**

option_settings:

aws:elasticbeanstalk:environment:proxy:

```
ProxyServer: nginx
```

then I added my nginx file:

**.ebextensions\files.config**

files:
    "/etc/nginx/conf.d/01_websockets.conf" :
        mode: "000644"
        owner: root
        group: root
        content : |
            worker_processes  1;

```
        events {
                worker_connections 2024;
        }


        http {
                include mime.types;
                default_type application/octet-stream;
                sendfile on;
                keepalive_timeout 65;
                gzip on;

                server {
                        listen 80;
                        server_name localhost;


                        location / {
                                proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
                                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
                                proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
                                proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy true; 

                                # prevents 502 bad gateway error
                                proxy_buffers 8 32k;
                                proxy_buffer_size 64k;

                                proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8080;
                                proxy_redirect off;

                                # enables WS support
                                proxy_http_version 1.1;
                                proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
                                proxy_set_header Connection  "upgrade";
                        }
                }
        }
```

Good luck!!!

Comment: If you have a NEW question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](//stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) button. If you have sufficient reputation, [you may upvote](//stackoverflow.com/privileges/vote-up) the question. Alternatively, "star" it as a favorite and you will be notified of any new answers.

Comment: Adding the following strings to nginx config helped me:

# enables WS support
proxy_http_version 1.1;
proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
proxy_set_header Connection  "upgrade";

Thanks!