# DefaultHandshakeHandler's determineUser not called on Production Server

Tags: amazon-web-services, tomcat, grails, amazon-ec2, spring-websocket

I have a grails project which uses Spring websockets. I have implemented the DefaultHandshakeHandler to create random principal name for each new session and use convertAndSendToUser to send messages.

**Everything works fine in local run. I am also able to deploy the WAR file on an AWS EC2 Linux Instance running latest tomcat. The file deploys fine and the Connect and Disconnect events on websockets can be detected correctly.***

**The only problem is, My CustomHandshakeHandler's determineUser does not get called on production.** Due to this my StompHeaderAccessor's principal is always null and the code starts spitting NPEs.

This is how i have declared the CustomHandshakeHandler :

```
class CustomHandshakeHandler extends DefaultHandshakeHandler {
    @Override
    protected Principal determineUser(ServerHttpRequest request,
                                      WebSocketHandler wsHandler,
                                      Map<String, Object> attributes) {
        // Generate principal with UUID as name
        return new StompPrincipal(UUID.randomUUID().toString())
    }
}
```

This is how i set the handshake handler configuration :

```
@Override
void registerStompEndpoints(StompEndpointRegistry stompEndpointRegistry) {
    stompEndpointRegistry.addEndpoint("/ws-ep") // Set websocket endpoint to connect to
                        .setHandshakeHandler(new CustomHandshakeHandler()) // Set custom handshake handler
                        .withSockJS() // Add Sock JS support for frontend
}
```

I tried deploying the same WAR file on local Tomcat 8 and it again works fine. It seems problem happens due to AWS. I also searched for some other AWS and websocket related issues. I came across some ELB compatibility related things but i Don't think that's my case since my websockets are working fine (Events are being received)

Can someone please help out or point me in right directions

Comment: May be the issue with a port on which you are running the web socket, verify that the port is open and have all the permissions (inbound/outbound) from AWS dashboard.

Comment: Thanks for the comment but problem was with the Nginx settings

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem was with Nginx settings which upgrade the Http Request to WS request. This question helped a lot : [Spring WebSocket: Handshake failed due to invalid Upgrade header: null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31211919/spring-websocket-handshake-failed-due-to-invalid-upgrade-header-null)